# What is/Why Marklogic Grove?

Tags: marklogic, grove

Just took a glance at the Grove documentation. It simply mentions about a middle-tier and a front-end providing some operations which were supposedly to be workaround on some areas. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I however did not understand the purpose of Grove and what benefit it would provide me or the project which is backed by Marklogic?

I don't have any knowledge about Marklogic. All I know is that it's a NoSql DB and I currently use some REST API endpoints exposed by it to do some basic search operations.

Before going through the documentation without understanding the context, it would be great if someone helps me out.
Would be helpful if explained with a use-case on what is this Grove about and why would I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Grove is intended to make it easy to build a simple search UI for a MarkLogic database. Consider a starting point from which you can make modifications, customizing to the needs of your application.

Grove is a community project, meaning that it's not officially supported but also that contributions from the developer community are welcome.